# How to get changed text through typeface?

Tags: android, typeface

I changed my text, English to Hindi through typeface. And I added it to `TextView`. It is working fine. After I tried to get the text of `TextView` it returns English language. I want it like converted(Hindi) language and add it to a string.

Please help me if any know how to do this.
Thanks in advance