# How to change the font language in android

Tags: java, android

In my app i want to convert my english font into hindi, for that i did localization. that is not supported for lower versions(i.e 2.3). Then i downloaded "**shusha.ttf**" file and added to assets/fonts folder. Then i set the typeface for a textviews. Like this i am able to convert the english font to hindi. but when i get the text from the text view it is not showing in Hindi(getting the english font). i am using that text to send the mail through gmail.

If any body have idea about this please give me a suggestion.

This is my Code

```
 t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
     t2 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2));
     Typeface Hindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shusha.ttf");
     t.setTypeface(Hindi);
     t.setTextSize(20);
     String hello=" Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India ";
     t.setText(hello);
     String lang=t.getText().toString().trim();
     t2.setText(lang);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977005/how-to-get-changed-text-through-typeface

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608520/how-to-get-hindi-fonts-in-android

Comment: t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
   t2 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2));
   Typeface Hindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shusha.ttf");
   t.setTypeface(Hindi);
   t.setTextSize(20);
   String hello=" Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India ";
   t.setText(hello);
   String lang=t.getText().toString().trim();
   t2.setText(lang);

Comment: Paste this code in your question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using and playing with font, use UNICODE characters for hindi words. I had done it for a project of mine and it works great.

Comment: Thank you autocrat, will you please give any sample for UNICODE characters for hindi?

Comment: Hi autocrat, do you have any example for using UNICODE characters for hindi Please give me..

Comment: Error // text in english
 
गलती //text in hindi

Comment: Try google translate. You can use those strings directly in your strings.xml

Comment: OK thank you, Is this unicode format is working for all versions of android devices? and one more doubt am i able to get the text from the textview in hindi format?

Comment: I have used it for labels only. AFAIK you can get the values as they are in Unicode and set them again. But how much sense your code will make out of those strings is a question mark.

Comment: I did that before by using google translate, but hindi font is visible like square boxes in htc android 2.3 version mobile. now i am looking for any other way to do this translation that support for all versions of android devices.

Comment: Did u try the Unicode string in 2.3? Unfortunately, I haven't tried on devices below 4.0! :(

Comment: yes i tried on 2.3 version, that is not working for below version.

Comment: Awww.. Thats sad. I had read somewhere that Android started supporting Devnagiri from 4.0. Please verify that and if thats the case you will need to use some other approach. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the font of the text of text view.

First put the font in your asset folder.

Then in your java file add code like this to change your font:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                    "shusha.ttf");
TextView digital= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
            digital.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Put shusha.ttf in your asset folder of your project.

This will might help you.

Comment: OK Andru thanks for your reply, when i get the text from that textbox it is not getting in hindi. Again it shows in english. is there any way to set the typeface for string variable.

Comment: Typeface can only change the font of the text in a perticuler text view. It cant change the string.

Answer (score 0):

Create styles in values/styles like,

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="typeface">font_in_assest.ttf</item>
</style>
```

Here, font_in_assest.ttf is the font you placed in your assests/fonts.
Then assign the style for you view,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/MyStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

It will be helpful for you..